# Fancy box closes when box is clicked wordpress comments

Tags: fancybox, wordpress

I am hardly trying to fix it but couldn't. I have the  code added to comments.php file so that if I select Leave a comment fancy box will open a popup window to post comments, it pops up but when I select the pop window it simply closes. My code is below. Please help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '100%',
        height      : '100%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
</script>
<div class="comment-buttons"><a href="#inline1" class="various" title="Leave a Comment">
                        Leave a Comment</a></div>
                        <div id="inline1" style="display: none;width:600px;height:410px;"><?php comment_form(); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself,

I added

> hideOnContentClick : false,

and that fixed then issue.

Comment: Your script shows options for fancybox v2.x which are not compatible with previous versions. `hideOnContentClick` is an option for fancybox v1.3.x